# SQL Server update multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table11 (Id, status). 
It's created in a test environment and I have full rights on this table.
sometimes I need to update it using the status'es from a different environment - lets call it table2. On this table/server I only have read rights
We have the data in different servers which cannot communicate due to security rules...so I have extract data from one environment and store it locally before updating.
I have MS SQL server

if I want to update 1 row I'll use

```
update Table set status = status1 where id = ID1
```

but I have a LOT of rows :) so far the best I can think of is using excel to generate a long list of update statements like the above one, but isn't there an easier/ more elegant way?

I only have read right on the table/server with the "correct data"

Comment: Is it always the same status for every ID or does the status change for different IDs?

Comment: To make things clearer, add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: It's different status and different iD's

Comment: for example: id: 1,2,3,4,5 today may have id's 2,6,7,1,1 and needs to be updated to 1,1,7,7,4

Comment: @MrsDahl still unclear example, do you mean that row with id=1 have status=2 today and you want to update status to 1? and id=2 to status 6->1 and so on?

Comment: Can you clarify what's your main goal? In my answer I assumed you wanted only to optimize the update because your tag is only SQL. Maybe your question is wider and it's also about sharing the status not using excel?  Do you have an application that acts as watchdog and collects the  statuses?

Comment: Daniel: I wish it was so simple...but no. Any status can change to any status...or keep it's current status:(

Comment: Do you have an application that acts as watchdog and collects the statuses? We dont have any application- and I doubt we'll ever get one. Thats why I'm trying to find the smartest way possible to get the values correct, so we can clean up regularly

Comment: You could make a SQL that generates a other SQL with the update statements, then you at least avoid excel... and only copy between Query windows in mgnmt studio

Comment: Thanks Daniel Stackenland. That is both within my (limited) skills and doable in my system(s). I'll probably use that method

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you suggesting without using Excel, here's a SQL Server example where `@tbl1` is on server 1 and `@tbl2` is on server 2:

```
DECLARE @tbl1 TABLE ( id INT, [status] NVARCHAR(10) )
DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE ( id INT, [status] NVARCHAR(10) )

-- @tbl1 data is different and needs to be sync'd to @tbl2
INSERT INTO @tbl1 ( id , [status] ) VALUES ( 1, 'd' ), ( 2, 'e' ), ( 3, 'f' )
INSERT INTO @tbl2 ( id , [status] ) VALUES ( 1, 'a' ), ( 2, 'b' ), ( 3, 'c' )

-- show current data
SELECT * FROM @tbl1 AS t
SELECT * FROM @tbl2 AS t

-- run a command like this on @tbl1 to generate UPDATE statements
SELECT 'UPDATE @tbl2 SET [status] = ''' + [status] + 
       ''' WHERE id = ' + CAST(t.id AS NVARCHAR(5))
FROM @tbl1 AS t

-- the above will generate this sql, which you can copy across and run on server 2
UPDATE @tbl2 SET [status] = 'd' WHERE id = 1
UPDATE @tbl2 SET [status] = 'e' WHERE id = 2
UPDATE @tbl2 SET [status] = 'f' WHERE id = 3

-- running the generated SQL on server 2 would then give you matching results
SELECT * FROM @tbl1 AS t
SELECT * FROM @tbl2 AS t
```

Instead of the standard *Results to grid* output, you can either display results as text or export to a file, to make copying/running the generated SQL easier, and possibly creating the first step of an automated process.

You'll find Query Result output options via the highlighted shortcuts below of via Tools > Options in the menu:

[image]

**Summary**

The actual SQL you will want to run on your source server is something like this:

```
-- run a command like this on @tbl1 to generate UPDATE statements
SELECT 'UPDATE @tbl2 SET [status] = ''' + [status] + 
       ''' WHERE id = ' + CAST(t.id AS NVARCHAR(5))
FROM @tbl1 AS t
```

Then you would take the results away to run on the target server.

Comment: Thanks - but I see I forgot to add that I only have read rights on table2/server2

Comment: then how do you perform an update query if you only have read rights? please add that to the question so that other users can see this information, although make it clear what permissions you have, as with read rights, you can't update?!